# you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression in sharepoint online management shell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

When we do this script in SharePoint Online Management Shell, we are getting the error as in pic...

> "you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code properly as text, then select it and press {} button or Ctrl-K to format it

Comment: Check what `$web` contains, i think it could be $null.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the incorrect PowerShell addin for what you're trying to do. SPOSite is for tenant management functions and does not open up the SharePoint object model (like Fields.AddFieldAsXml). You need to use SharePoint Client SDK instead which you can [download here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

And then your powershell will look like this:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" #loads sharepoint client runtime
$destination = "http://my.sharepoint.com/url"
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($destination)
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password) #You can also pass a credential here if you want that dialog prompt instead of $username and $password
$myNewField = $context.Web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($fieldXML)
$context.Load($myNewField)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```